# Understanding dmesg messages

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am a newbie learning how to write Linux device drivers for USB devices. I want to understand the dmesg ouput

```
[ 6870.420077] usb 2-5: new low-speed USB device number 43 using ohci_hcd
[ 6870.500057] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[ 6871.444057] usb 2-5: new low-speed USB device number 44 using ohci_hcd
[ 6871.524065] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
[ 6872.468089] usb 2-5: new low-speed USB device number 45 using ohci_hcd
[ 6872.548065] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
```

Could you direct me to some reading material explaining how to decipher these kernel messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dmesg** - print or control the kernel ring buffer.

when `dmesg` command is issued, kernel ring buffer messages will be printed. There is no specific format used I guess.

Mostly whenever a new driver(or kernel code) is written, that particular module name is print first and corresponding message will be printed for differentiating our messages.

for example,

`printk(KERN_ALERT "JayModule: Module loaded successfully.. ");`

will print `JayModule: Module loaded successfully..` in kernel ring buffer.

I guess numeric values given within [] is time.